# Windows 10 starts slow with 3 HDDs connected

Tags: windows-10, boot

I have the OS installed on a 500GB Samsung SSD and an additional 5TB storage on my PC. I noticed that if I start the PC with all 4 drives, it takes about 1.5 minutes, and if I disconnect 3 HDD's (2x2TB and 1x1TB) and leave only the SSD, it takes about 6 seconds to start. What could be the problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select **First Level**, **CPU**, **DiskIO**, **FileIO** and under **Performance Scenario** select **Boot**. **Number of iteration** can be set to **1** and click to start. This reboots Windows and captures all activity during boot. After the reboot let the countdown tick to 0. repeat this now when the 3 HDDs are removed. Zip the 2 large ETL files into zip/RAR file, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here. I'll analyze the difference and post it

Comment: have you captured the 2 traces? otherwise I'll vote to close the question as "too broad", because without the traces we can't help you.